# Load 16 bit integers in AVX2 vector?

Tags: c, vector, avx2

I am new to AVX programming. I want to load a `__m256` vector with 16 short int or 16 bit values, But I'm unable to do so.

Here is my attempt. It gives the following error:

> incompatible types when initializing type ‘__m256’ using type ‘int’
>         __m256 result = _mm256_load_epi16((__m256*)&int_array);

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <immintrin.h>

int main() {
  int i;

  short int int_array[16] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16};


  __m256 result = _mm256_load_epi16((__m256*)&int_array);

  short int* res = (short int*)&result;
  printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d\n", res[0], res[1], res[2], res[3], res[4], res[5], res[6], res[7]);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try to replace `short int int_array[16]` with `char int_array[16]` and replace `_mm256_load_epi16((__m256*)&int_array);` with `_mm256_load_epi16((__m256*)int_array);`

Comment: I did the changes although I want to load 16 bit integers instead of 8 bit chars, but got the same error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
__m256i integer_vector = _mm256_load_si256((__m256*)int_array);
```

Three problems:

- **you ignored your compiler's implicit-declaration warning for `_mm256_load_epi16`, which doesn't exist**.  That's why it's complaining about initializing a `__m256i` from an `int`.
- `int_array` is already a pointer to the first element.  `&int_array` is a pointer to a pointer.  You don't want to load that.
- `__m256` is a vector of 8 floats.  You want `__m256i`.  (The intrinsics distinguish between integer, float, and double vectors.  This matches the asm instructions: using the result of an integer vector operation as an input to an FP vector operation (and vice versa) can cause extra bypass-delay latency.  This stops you from casually / accidentally using an FP shuffle on integer data.  It's still worth it sometimes, which is why functions like `__m128 _mm_castsi128_ps(__m128i)` exist.)

---

There aren't separate intrinsics for loads/stores with different integer element sizes.  This is why you always have to write those annoying casts to `(__m256i*)`.  (AVX512 intrinsics will take `void*` args, a much better design IMO.)

Intel's intrinsics finder (https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/) will help you find the functions you need.  See also the [sse](/questions/tagged/sse) tag wiki for guides, and the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki has good stuff.

---

**Fourth problem:** You didn't align your array, so using an aligned-load intrinsic isn't safe.  You can use a `loadu` intrinsic instead.

---

#### Fifth problem:

`short int* res = (short int*)&result;` is a bad idea.  Don't alias pointers onto vectors.  Aliasing vector-pointers onto arrays is ok, because `__m256i` is defined with a "may alias" attribute.  But dereferencing `(short int*)&result` is C/C++ Undefined Behaviour, and won't do what you want (in theory or in practice).

Store to a temporary array, use `_mm_extract_epi16`, or use a union for type-punning.

Comment: Changed the code as you mentioned. Still getting the error, but a different one.

Comment: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘_mm256_load_si256’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
   __m256 result =_mm256_load_si256((__m256*)int_array);
   ^
include/immintrin.h:56:0,
                 from test.c:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/include/avxintrin.h:869:1: note: expected ‘const __vector(4) long long int *’ but argument is of type ‘__vector(8) float *’
 _mm256_load_si256 (__m256i const *__P)
 ^

Comment: error: incompatible types when initializing type ‘__m256’ using type ‘__m256i’
   __m256 result =_mm256_load_si256((__m256*)int_array);

Comment: @user2764478: notice the difference between `__m256` (float vector) and `__m256i` (integer vector).

Comment: changed 
__m256i result =_mm256_load_si256((__m256i*)int_array);
compiled but gave segmentation fault.

Comment: @user2764478: because your array isn't aligned.  Use C++11 `alignas(32)`, or whatever other way of aligning it.  Or use an unaligned load intrinsic.  Or better, use `_mm256_setr_epi16(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16);`.

Comment: I want to make the code dynamic, so setr isn't option.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. Can you please elaborate on the fifth problem you mentioned?

Comment: @user2764478: google `type-pun pointer cast union` to learn why C++ aliasing rules make it unsafe in general to type-pun with pointer casts, while many compilers do support using unions.  In ISO C++, the only safe way is memcpy.  Compilers can usually optimize it away, and use the data in-place without copying, but nobody likes writing `memcpy` for that, so the union method remains popular.  GNU C/C++ does guarantee that writing one member of union and then reading another is safe, but ISO C/C++ leave it as UB.